# how to preserve input state of ngb-accordion on collapse

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

Is it possible to save state (entered text) of the input when collapsing ngb-accordion?

Here is example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ukshlz-wz6st8?file=app/accordion-basic.html

If you enter some text into input and collapse / expand first panel then input loose it's contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use a variable and ngModel

```
myinput:any; //in your .ts

<input [(ngModel)]="myinput">  //your .html make use of the variable
```

**Updated** made by @tilias

if you use complex component structure, another possibility is setting **destroyOnHide** to *false*

```
<ngb-accordion [destroyOnHide]="false">
```

This will prevent destroying component, which holds your input and it's binding: [see the docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/api#NgbPanel)

while I updated the answer, Tilias found the correct solution: remove my update

Comment: My case is more complex: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3kmxzmy26crnks/input-lose-text.gif?dl=0 If there won't be any other suggestions I will mark your answer as correct though. I already have binding in custom component but it seems when panel is collapsed component is destroyed

Comment: Eliseo, I have updated your comment for second use-case. I have also tested it and indeed destroyOnHide was the reason. As soon as somebody approve my edit, I will accept it as an answer. Many thanks for pointing me in the correct direction!

Comment: I'm afraid that you need use ngOnDestroy to store the variables in a service (or in parent) and ngOnInit for give the value to yours variables (I updated the answer)